# custom class method access

Tags: android, class, sharedpreferences

I have problem with accessing my custom class methods which handles loads and saves.
While they were is the same class those methods worked as intend. But since I decided to reuse the save/load methods couple of times I needed them in separate class, but when I try to access those method the program crashes, anybody have a solution with an explanation why? 
Maybe the problem is with MODE_PRIVATE but I tried changing it and it still crashes

```
package com.main.kanji_sama;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

import com.main.customClass.sharedPreferences;

public class Hiragana extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    CheckBox cb1,cb2;
    Button backButton;
    sharedPreferences myFunction = new sharedPreferences();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hiragana);


        cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.hiragana_xx_check);
        cb1.setChecked(myFunction.loadSharedPref("cb1"));
        cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.hiragana_kx_check);
        cb2.setChecked(myFunction.loadSharedPref("cb2"));

        backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hiraganaconfbutton);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(Hiragana.this, Main.class));   
    }
    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.hiragana_xx_check:
            myFunction.saveSharedPref("cb1",checked);
        break;  
        case R.id.hiragana_kx_check:
            myFunction.saveSharedPref("cb2", checked);

    }
}
}
**This is my class**

public class sharedPreferences extends Activity {

    public boolean loadSharedPref(String key){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Kanji-Sama", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
        }
    public void saveSharedPref(String key,boolean value){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Kanji-Sama", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
        }
}
```

Comment: You can not instantiate `Activity` manually. and you need to consider redesigning your code...

Answer (score 0):

your class has extends Activity.

```
public class sharedPreferences extends Activity
```

Try remove extends Activity and add class member Context, Constructor pass the Context(getApplicationContext().
and you change your class in method use the class member.